# No implementation found for void org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals

Tags: android, webrtc

I have a strange and frustrating problem.

I'm building an Android app using the Open Whisper systems webrtc library.

I'm including this package via gradel...

```
compile 'org.whispersystems:webrtc-android:M59'
```

This has worked happily for the last 2 weeks (and the previous version for a month before). But, today I get the following run-time error...

```
No implementation found for void `org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(android.content.Context, boolean) (tried Java_org_webrtc_PeerConnectionFactory_initializeAndroidGlobals and Java_org_webrtc_PeerConnectionFactory_initializeAndroidGlobals__Landroid_content_Context_2Z)`
```

I've cleaned and rebuilt the project but the problem persists. Any clues?

Edit -

This error happens on a Pixel running Android 7.1.2
but I've just found that it works fine on a Samsung running Android 6.0.1

Comment: seems you installed armeabi-debug apk instead of armeabi-v7a-debug that why native library missed check once

Answer (score -1):

The problem was because the app was trying to use an external library with 32 bit code (Webrtc) and  64bit code (Realm). The solution was to exclude the 64bit Realm from the build.

see here...

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#couldnt-load-librealm-jniso

Comment: HI, are fixing a Real Database problem or a webrtc native libs problem?

Comment: I'm using the Google webrtc library now, no problems in using that.

Comment: The reason I asked is that am stuck with org.webrtc.Logging: NativeLibrary: Failed to load native library: jingle_peerconnection_so. I don't know what could be the problem.

Comment: I have added signal's libnativeutils.so under jnli libs and also included the cpp and header files under jni. What could I be misssing